# Vue CLI. Publish with subdomains

Tags: apache, docker, vue.js, nginx, vue-cli

I need to publish Vue CLI project that supports dynamic subdomains. 
The main idea is that every request on *.example.com will come on root directory dist/index.html.

What i tried:
Nginx server name *.example.com / server alias.
Apache server alias *.example.com

Main request example.com - is ok, but *.example.com not working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Users/admin/Sites/example/dist"
        ServerName example.local
        ServerAlias *.example.local
        #VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/admin/Sites/example/dist
        #<Directory "/Users/admin/Sites/example/dist/">
        #       AllowOverride All
        #       Require local
        #       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        #       Order Deny,Allow
        #       Allow from all
        #       Deny from all
        #       #Require all granted
        #</Directory>
        ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/example-error_log"
        CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/example-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

server {
        listen       8080;
        root /Users/admin/Sites/example/dist;
        server_name *.example.local;

        location / {
            #root   dist;
            #index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
```

I think i tried all of google-advices. But no luck. I found out that ServerAlias doesnt work at all.

I have Apache 2.4, and mac os system.

Has anyone encountered such a problem? It turned out to solve? Maybe there are other ways?

Thank you!